# jfreechart - customizing Pie chart labels for each pie

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to add custom renderers for each pie chart on my graph based on the type of data that is being passed (integer vs dollar amount vs percentage). But, the data in a `PieDataset` seems to only have 1 key (whereas, when the dataset is created as a `DefaultCategoryDataset` it has a `rowKey` and a `columnKey`).

In the picture below, what I am trying to achieve is the graph on the right ("Sales Total") would show dollar amounts (`$ #,##0.00`).

[image]

What I tried: I tried creating a custom renderer and passing in an ENUM of the datatype, but that didn't work because the data type because I was unable to determine within the renderer which pie was being rendered:

```
    static class CustomLabelGenerator implements PieSectionLabelGenerator {
        public String generateSectionLabel(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key) {
            NumberFormat nf;
            // How do you find out which pie is being rendered? "key" relates to Bob, Sally, George, Tom, etc.
            switch (data_type) {
                case currency:
                    nf = new DecimalFormat("$ #,##0.00");
                    break;
                case integer:
                    nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");
                    break;
                case percentage:
                    nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00 %");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid ENUM. This is impossible");
            }
            return nf.format(dataset.getValue(key));
        }
        public AttributedString generateAttributedSectionLabel(
                PieDataset dataset, Comparable key) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Is this even possible? All the jFreeChart multiple pie chart demos show symmetric data types across all the pie charts on the same screen. Does this need to be separated into two separate graphs/panels? That would be unfortunate if so...

Here's the SSCCE (if you have jFreeChart library):

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.text.AttributedString;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.PieSectionLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.MultiplePiePlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset;
import org.jfree.util.TableOrder;

/**
 * This example is similar to {@link MultiplePieChartDemo1}, but slices the
 * dataset by column rather than by row.
 */
public class MultiplePieChart extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates a sample dataset.
     *
     * @return A sample dataset.
     */
    private static CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        int bob_quantity = 100;
        int sally_quantity = 115;
        int george_quantity = 112;
        int tom_quantity = 99;
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.addValue(bob_quantity, "Bob", "Sales Quantity");
        dataset.addValue(sally_quantity, "Sally", "Sales Quantity");
        dataset.addValue(george_quantity, "George", "Sales Quantity");
        dataset.addValue(tom_quantity, "Tom", "Sales Quantity");

        double bob_total = 1450.40;
        double sally_total = 1545.12;
        double george_total = 1550.56;
        double tom_total = 1200.90;
        dataset.addValue(bob_total, "Bob", "Sales Total");
        dataset.addValue(sally_total, "Sally", "Sales Total");
        dataset.addValue(george_total, "George", "Sales Total");
        dataset.addValue(tom_total, "Tom", "Sales Total");

        return dataset;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a sample chart with the given dataset.
     *
     * @param dataset  the dataset.
     *
     * @return A sample chart.
     */
    private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset, String chartTitle, boolean includeLegend, Data_Type data_type) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createMultiplePieChart(
            chartTitle,  // chart title
            dataset,               // dataset
            TableOrder.BY_COLUMN,
            includeLegend,                  // include legend
            true,
            false
        );
        MultiplePiePlot plot = (MultiplePiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        plot.setOutlineStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));

        JFreeChart subchart = plot.getPieChart();
        PiePlot p = (PiePlot) subchart.getPlot();

        p.setBackgroundPaint(null);
        p.setOutlineStroke(null);
        p.setStartAngle(0);

//        p.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} ({2})",
//                NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(),
//                NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()));
        p.setMaximumLabelWidth(0.20);

        p.setLabelGenerator(new CustomLabelGenerator(data_type));


        return chart;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a panel for the demo (used by SuperDemo.java).
     *
     * @return A panel.
     */
    public static JPanel createPanel(CategoryDataset dataset, Dimension size, String chartTitle, boolean includeLegend, Data_Type data_type) {
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, chartTitle, includeLegend, data_type);
        ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
        if(size != null)
            panel.setPreferredSize(size);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = createPanel(createDataset(), new Dimension(800, 500), "Sales", true, Data_Type.integer);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


    enum Data_Type {
        integer,
        percentage,
        currency
    }

    static class CustomLabelGenerator implements PieSectionLabelGenerator {


        private final Data_Type data_type;

        public CustomLabelGenerator(Data_Type data_type) {
            this.data_type = data_type;
        }

        public String generateSectionLabel(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key) {
            NumberFormat nf;
            switch (data_type) {
                case currency:
                    nf = new DecimalFormat("$ #,##0.00");
                    break;
                case integer:
                    nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");
                    break;
                case percentage:
                    nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00 %");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid ENUM. This is impossible");
            }
            return nf.format(dataset.getValue(key));
        }

        public AttributedString generateAttributedSectionLabel(
                PieDataset dataset, Comparable key) {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the most elegant solution, but if all of your types will be different types of numbers (`int`, `double`, `float`) you can instantiate them as objects (e.g. `Integer bob_quantity = 100`) and then do an `instance of` check on the value in the label generator.

Comment: It's not a bad thought. Actually, all of the `dataset` values are `Number` class, and I've been successful at passing in and deciphering between `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` (since they extend the `Number` class). The only problem is deciphering percentages vs currency values (they would both be represented as `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feels a little kludgy, but it seems to work. What I'm doing is taking the `PieDataset` passed to `generateSectionLabel` and figuring out which column it is in your original `CategoryDataset`. It is my understanding that `CategoryToPieDataset#equals(PieDataset)` is comparing all of the keys and values to see if they match. This approach doesn't use your enum at all, it just looks at which column it is generating for:

```
static class CustomLabelGenerator implements PieSectionLabelGenerator {
  private final CategoryDataset catDataset;

  public CustomLabelGenerator(CategoryDataset catDataset) {
    this.catDataset = catDataset;
  }

  public String generateSectionLabel(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key) {
    int column = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < catDataset.getColumnCount(); c++) {
      CategoryToPieDataset categoryToPieDataset = 
          new CategoryToPieDataset(catDataset, TableOrder.BY_COLUMN, c);
      if (categoryToPieDataset.equals(dataset)) {
        column = c;
        break;
      }
    }
    NumberFormat nf;
    switch (column) {
      case 0: // the 'Sales Quantity' column
        nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");
        break;
      case 1: // the 'Sales Total' column
        nf = new DecimalFormat("$ #,##0.00");
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid column. This is impossible");
    }
    return nf.format(dataset.getValue(key));
  }
}
```

The result:
[image: result]

Unless someone more familiar with the JFree API has a better solution, it would probably be cleaner to just create single pie charts and throw them in an `X_AXIS` `BoxLayout`.

Comment: +1 for either approach: 1) conditional generator or 2) separate generators.

Comment: I found your solution to be slightly more capable (but much less elegant) than just doing a test for `dataset.getValue(key) instanceof BigInteger`. In the end, the labels actually created a lot of clutter on my actual solution so I had to get rid of them anyways and just rely on mouseover tooltip to convey the information. I marked yours as the answer, though. Very creative solution!